# How can I get column names via PDO/Sqlite when query returns no records?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

The following code allows me to pass an SQL statement to a class and call its method to display a nice table of the results, including column names.

However, **if there are no results, I still want the column names** to be displayed.

Unfortunately, `getColumnMeta` is not returning any data as it does in other examples I have found.

**Does anyone know how to get getColumnMeta() working in this example, or another way I can get the names of the fields from the SQL statement when the query returns zero rows?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            table thead tr td {
                background-color: #ddd;
                padding: 5px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            table tbody tr td {
                background-color: #eee;
                padding: 5px;
                color: navy;
            }
            div.sqlCommand {
                font-family: courier;
            }

            h2 {
                border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

        $sql = 'SELECT LastName,FirstName,Title FROM employee WHERE 1=2 ORDER BY LastName';

        echo '<h2>sqlite</h2>';
        $dbSqlite = new DbSqlite($sql);
        echo $dbSqlite -> displayHtmlTable();

        class DbSqlite {
            protected $sql;
            protected $records = array();
            protected $columnNames = array();
            public function __construct($sql) {
                $this -> sql = $sql;
                $this -> initialize();
            }

            protected function initialize() {
                $db = new PDO('sqlite:chinook.sqlite');
                $result = $db -> query($this -> sql);
                $result -> setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $columnsAreDefined = false;
                while ($row = $result -> fetch()) {
                    $this -> records[] = $row;
                    if (!$columnsAreDefined) {
                        foreach ($row as $columnName => $dummy) {
                            $this -> columnNames[] = $columnName;
                        }
                        $columnsAreDefined = true;
                    }
                }

                if (count($this -> records) == 0) {
                    $total_column = $result -> columnCount();
                    var_dump($total_column);

                    for ($x = 0; $x < $total_column; $x++) {
                        $meta = $result -> getColumnMeta($x);
                        //var_dump($meta);
                        //bool(false)
                        //$column[] = $meta['name'];
                    }
                }
            }

            public function displayHtmlTable() {
                $r = '';

                $r .= '<div class="sqlCommand">' . $this -> sql . '</div>';

                $r .= '<table>';

                $r .= '<thead>';
                $r .= '<tr>';
                foreach ($this->columnNames as $columnName) {
                    $r .= '<td>' . $columnName . '</td>';
                }
                $r .= '</tr>';
                $r .= '</thead>';

                $r .= '<tbody>';
                foreach ($this->records as $record) {
                    $r .= '<tr>';
                    foreach ($record as $data) {
                        $r .= '<td>' . $data . '</td>';
                    }
                    $r .= '</tr>';
                }
                $r .= '</tbody>';
                $r .= '<table>';
                return $r;
            }

        }
        ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: But your query has the column names, is it important that PDO returns them?

Comment: right, but if I send a `SELECT *` then I need to rely on PDO to get the column names from the database.

Comment: fair enough, just wondered if you were overthinking it

Answer (score 4):

Meta table `sqlite_master` contains all information. Following code will parse `sqlite_master` into column names as `$colnames`:

```
$colnames = array() ;

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name = 'put_table_name_here'") ;
$stmt->execute() ;
$row = $stmt->fetch() ;

$sql = $row[0] ;
$r = preg_match("/\(\s*(\S+)[^,)]*/", $sql, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) ;
while ($r) {
  array_push( $colnames, $m[1][0] ) ;
  $r = preg_match("/,\s*(\S+)[^,)]*/", $sql, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $m[0][1] + strlen($m[0][0]) ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. First approach I would try:

   - run the query
   - check if there were results returned
   - if yes, run Your `initialize()` and `displayHtmlTable`
   - if **no**, run Your `initializeEmptyResult()` that will run the next query and just fills `$this->columnNames[]`:

```sql
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'my_table_name'
```

The query is dependent on MySQL bu there should be more alternatives for other databases, or still You can run `DESCRIBE table` and parse columns names from the result (should be SQL DBMS undependent).

1. Second that is I think easier to accomplish: if there are no results returned from the query, do not display a coulmn names nor table at all, just display a message: 'No results found.'. This could be achieved within Your `displayHtmlTable` method:

   ```
       public function displayHtmlTable() {
           $r = '';

           $r .= '<div class="sqlCommand">' . $this -> sql . '</div>';

           if(count($this->records) > 0) {
               $r .= '<table>';

               $r .= '<thead>';
               $r .= '<tr>';
               foreach ($this->columnNames as $columnName) {
                   $r .= '<td>' . $columnName . '</td>';
               }
               $r .= '</tr>';
               $r .= '</thead>';

               $r .= '<tbody>';
               foreach ($this->records as $record) {
                   $r .= '<tr>';
                   foreach ($record as $data) {
                       $r .= '<td>' . $data . '</td>';
                   }
                   $r .= '</tr>';
               }
               $r .= '</tbody>';
               $r .= '<table>';
           } else {
               $r .= '<div class="no-results">No results found for query.</div>';
           }

           return $r;
       }
   ```

And You do not have to bother with column names...

**EDIT:** For the first case found a query for SQLite that should do the same as `select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'xxx'`:

```
PRAGMA table_info(table-name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on @shadyyx comment:

> `PRAGMA table_info(table-name);`

I don't have a PDO_SQLITE sandbox handy, but using the native SQLite3 driver, this snippet will get you the column names for table **table-name** in **$arrColumns**:

```
$db = new SQLite3('db.sqlite');
$db->query('PRAGMA table_info(table-name)');
while ($col = $res->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    $arrColnames[]=$col['name'];
}
print_r($arrColnames);
```