# PDO to return column names based on select query

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

im trying to get the column names based on the query I send in to PDO. Unfortunately I do not know anything except the query at this moment. I know that I can get the associated array from the statement but what if the table is empty? I still need the column names at least to show an empty result in the table.

**MENTION: This is a SQLite DB.**

Let's say I have this query:

```
 select 1+1 as 'addition', id, column1, column2 from table
```

If I try to get the columns from table by reading the table information from the DB it will show

```
 id:int, column1:text, column2:text
```

and leave out my "addition" column. This is misleading for me and would not result in a correct data array.

Any suggestions how to get all the column names based on the query?

Best regards,

GT

Comment: See [PDOStatement::columnCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.columncount.php) and [PDOStatement::getColumnMeta](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php)

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the tip but getColumnMeta seems to be experimental and may change. Is it really a good practice to use this then?

Comment: You have a choice between an experimental API or nothing. If you're worried about it changing, don't upgrade your PDO version.

Comment: More specifically, check the release notes of the new version of PDO. If it changes, I expect it to be mentioned there.

Comment: @Barmar, Indeed, I will experiment with this and if I can solve this by your mentioning, I will accept that as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar, due to my lack of information I have updated the question. Seems those functions does not work for SQLite. I have implemented a function but I get null back for every column index. Seems this question has addressed this as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016555/how-can-i-get-column-names-via-pdo-sqlite-when-query-returns-no-records I can still use this solution because I need to implement same functionality for MySQL.

Comment: @Barmar, Is this really a duplicate since my question differs. I want to get the columns for a select with "dynamic columns" such as 1+1 as 'addition'? What I was referring to was that getColumnMeta is not behaiving correctly in combination of SQLite and PDO.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that difference.

Comment: The solution may be to use a different API than PDO, that provides this information.

Comment: @Barmar, no worries. :)